# mongoexport csv without ObjectID()

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

I am trying to export raw data from MongoDB with mongoexport. I want it to be in a readable state once I try to import it to other sources.

The main problem I am currently having is that the **ObjectId** also comes out with the output.

Example of output from csv:

> ,[],,,,,,,,[],,,,,,,,,185,113.3,113.3,0,0,113.3,113.3,,185.0,,,,,,,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,0,,,,,,,,,1665,1019.6999999999999,1019.6999999999999,0,0,1019.7,1019.7,,1665.0,,,,,,,,,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,0,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,0,0,0,,,,,,,0,0,0,0,,0,,,-1133,-1133,0,0,-1133,-1133,,0,0,**ObjectId**(5f80995d0ea68145cd01f9b0),**ObjectId**(5f3ac3e38bcf0d75a59ff139),

The ObjectID is making it difficult to import data into my other sources.

Is there a way to get just the raw data or just the raw values of these to the csv?